# async.js each with object method?

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, mocha.js, async.js

I have an object with a bunch of functions attached to it, and some tests that I want run against each element in a list of these objects. So I've put tests in these object-methods and want to run them all in an `async.each`.

#### Attempt (CoffeeScript + Mocha)

```coffee
{format} = require 'util'
async    = require 'async'

class Foo
    constructor: (@bar) ->

class Bar extends Foo
    whoami_sync: => @bar
    whoami_async: (cb) => cb null, @bar

objects = [{foo:'bar'}, {bar:'foo'}].map (obj) -> new Bar obj

describe 'something', ->
    it "does't", (done) ->
        async.each objects, ((item) ->
            objects[objects.indexOf(item)].whoami_async), done

    it 'does', (done) ->
        res_list = [obj.whoami_sync() for obj in objects]
        console.log format '[obj.whoami_sync() for obj in objects] = %j', res_list
        done if res_list.filter((elem) -> !elem.length).length then new Error else null
```

#### Error output (sync test passes)

> 1) something doesn't:
>      Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded

Comment: shouldn't that be `.map()` rather than `.forEach()`?

Comment: Whoops, yeah. Rewrote my longer example in this short test-case, must've forgotten to check that line.

Comment: `objects[objects.indexOf(item)]` looks like a long way to write `item`. You should call the `whoami_sync` method, not just refer to it. Ordinary methods should be created with `->`, not `=>`.

Comment: Hmm, you're right about the first one. Wonder why I was writing it like that? - As for the second, if I need to access `self` don't I need `=>`?

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to [async.each](https://github.com/caolan/async#each) is an iterator function that should take two arguments, not one; the second one should be called when the iterator's work is done. For instance, this works:

```
async.each [1, 2, 3],
    ((x, next) -> console.log x; do next),
    ((err) -> console.log 'done')
```

If your iterator is asynchronous, pass the function to the async operation so that it can call it on completion:

```
asyncOp = (x, next) ->
    console.log "checking #{x}"
    if x > 1
        next "#{x} is too big"
    else
        next null

async.each [1, 2, 3],
    ((x, next) -> asyncOp x, next),
    (err) -> console.log err
```

Comment: Thanks, but that still isn't working cleanly with my `cb` handler. I.e.: `async.each objects, ((item, next) -> objects[objects.indexOf(item)].whoami_async; do next), done` will always succeed, even when it's defined like: `whoami_async: (cb) => cb new Error`.

Comment: You have to give `next` to `whoami_async` so that it can call it on completion.

Comment: Perfect, that works. Edit you answer to be like that and I'll accept.